# Calculate combinations with complex restrictions for large N, efficiently

Tags: python, optimization, vectorization, combinations

I have a list of 32 unique elements. Each element is represented by a unique key and the value can be one of 3 types: `A`, `B` and `C`.

```py
elements = {1: 'A',
            2: 'A',
            3: 'B', 
            4: 'C', 
            ...
            ...
            32: 'B'}
```

Types are not represented equally, i.e.: type `B` may appear more times than type `A` or `C`.

I need to get all possible combinations that follow these restrictions:

- must be composed of 6 elements
- exactly 2 instances of each type are allowed (no less, no more)
- no repetitions of the key
- order is irrelevant

Example (simplified notation):

- `[1A, 12A, 3B, 6B, 4C, 5C]`: contains 2xA, 2xB, 2xC

Is there a way to do this efficiently, using matrices/vectorization or sets and unions/interections?

I could probably get all combinations using `itertools.combinations(elements, r=6)` with some little adjustment, but I am not sure of how to efficiently enfore these rules without having to loop through all (906,192) combinations.

Comment: Just to understand: what's wrong with iterating 906,192 elements? Do you need to call such functions many times?

Comment: You should probably create a reverse mapping from value to keys. I.e. `{"A": [1, 2,...], ["B": 3,...,32]}` etc. Then you can simply randomly choose (without replacement) two indices out of each of the original values. This is a very efficient way.

Comment: @Itay trying to be as efficient as possible, mostly as an exercise. However, my list of elements may grow over time which will result in more and more combinations. The reverse mapping idea sounds like the right thing to do; I will give it a go.